# Determine if string is even or odd length with regular expression

Tags: regex

I am having trouble building a regular expression with the set of strings over `{a, b, c}` that is an `odd` length with **exactly** one `a`.  Here is my best attempt so far:

```
(bb|bc|cb|cc)*a(bb|bc|cb|cc)*
```

This does good for even `b` and `c` on either side of the `a`, but does not account for a odd `b` and `c` combination on either side of the `a`.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string will be a *prefix* followed by *a* followed by a *suffix*.

Both *prefix* and *suffix* can be zero length. If not, they have to be either both even or both uneven. This means you have two main cases.

```
EVENPREFIX a EVENSUFFIX | UNEVENPREFIX a UNEVENSUFFIX
```

Try this (**incomplete** and **wrong**):

```
([bc][bc])*a([bc][bc])*|([bc][bc][bc])*a([bc][bc][bc])*
```

There is still one uneven case missing: a single `[bc]`:

```
(([bc][bc])*a([bc][bc])*)|([bc]([bc][bc])*a[bc]([bc][bc])*)
```

According to http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm, this matches

- `a`
- `cac`
- `ccabb`

I expect it matches the rest too...

The left side guarantees even (or empty) sequences of `b` or `c`.
The right side is either a single `b` or `c` followed by a multiple of two (so that it stays uneven).

**Kobi came up with this refinement of the above:**

```
([bc][bc])*(a|[bc]a[bc])([bc][bc])*
```

How does this work?

The first group is guaranteed to be even. The second group is guaranteed to be uneven with a single `a` inside. The third group is guaranteed to be be even. Thus, the whole is guaranteed to be uneven.

Comment: You can simplify that to `([bc][bc])*(a|[bc]a[bc])([bc][bc])*` - apply alternation only where you need it.

Comment: The square brackets will not work because that means match exactly once.  The string `a` by itself should be a valid string since it is odd, your regex does not account for a by itself.

Comment: @Kobi Right. Thank you for pointing that out. This is a different train of thought, though...

Comment: @typoknig - wrong, because it's in a group with an asterisk. Also, don't forget `^...$`.

Comment: @Kobi, yours is dead on.  Now I just need to try and understand it how why :)

Comment: @typoknig Of course it does: zero occurrences of `([bc][bc])` followed by `a` followed by zero occurrences of `([bc][bc])` *is* `a` by itself.

Comment: Oh, actually, the first regex is wrong, it doesn't match `ca`, or `ccccca`, etc.

Comment: I couldn't get @Daren's original solutions (either of the two) to match a single `a`.

Comment: `ca` is invalid (even). so is `ccccca`. Aren't those not part of the language?

Comment: @typoknig - this might be a case of grouping and how tightly the | operator binds...

Comment: After looking at it for a few minutes I get it now, the first and last group of `[bc]` catches every `b` or `c` occurring in an even amount, while the middle group takes care of the single `a` and any odd `b` and `c` that may occur on either side of the `a`.  Thanks a lot for your help guys!